# One to many relationship excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a list of part's and their quantities. These parts are used to build sub assemblies and are also used with the sub assemblies to build the final product. These parts are used on multiple products and various sub assemblies. I have all the data of each product, their parts and then the parts of the sub assemblies. However I am looking for a way to build a "tier" list kind of thing in my excel sheet (could be in a table) that will show how many of each part I need if I were to order x of product A and x of product B.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYz38.png)

Comment: This may be a decent starting point. https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/05/08/dynamic-bill-of-material-bom-solution-in-excel-and-powerbi/

Comment: @Olly This is what I've been looking for! Thank you.